# Change OSSEC alert emails "From" header

Tags: email, alerts, ossec

I'd like to know how to change the name in the "From" header for emails sent by OSSEC. I couldn't find any information about that.

Alerts I receive from my server are quite well organized. And OSSEC and is the only one I was not able to customize yet.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
ok
then this could be compiled in sources:

```
os_maild/sendcustomemail.c:#define FROM    "From: OSSEC HIDS <%s>\r\n"
os_maild/sendmail.c:#define FROM    "From: OSSEC HIDS <%s>\r\n"
```

use your custom name, and then run ./install.sh again, and answer yes -> update.

Comment: You're right but sorry, I forgot to mention I'd like to change the name in the from header (edited the question above), not the email address.